# find the selected value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the **td nth-child(7) value is dynamically**

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>CTU2020062310272</td>
    <td>12079404 - CIF00000000062323</td>
    <td>0001-KAULA LAMPUR</td>
    <td>Hong Leong Bank</td>
    <td>23-06-2020</td>
    <td>Invoice Financing</td>
    <td>23-06-2020</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>CTU2020062310272</td>
    <td>12079404 - CIF00000000062323</td>
    <td>0001-KAULA LAMPUR</td>
    <td>Hong Leong Bank</td>
    <td>23-06-2020</td>
    <td>Letter</td>
    <td>23-06-2020</td>
</tr>
```

my js code

```
 $(document).on('click', '.authpenrighttable tr', function(){
        if(($(this).find('td input')).is(':checked')){
            $(this).find('td input').prop('checked', false);
        } else{
            $(this).find('td input').prop('checked', true);
            var docvalue = $(this).children('td:nth-child(7)').val();
            console.log(docvalue);
        }
    })
```

I can apply **style and change the value** but **not getting the value**

Answer (score 1):

You should first target the closest *tr* element then find the element. Also there is no value attribute of *td* element, you have to use `text()`:

```
var docvalue = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(7)').text();
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.authpenrighttable tr', function(){
  if(($(this).find('td input')).is(':checked')){
    $(this).find('td input').prop('checked', false);
  } else{
    $(this).find('td input').prop('checked', true);
    var docvalue = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(7)').text();
    console.log(docvalue);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="authpenrighttable">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>CTU2020062310272</td>
    <td>12079404 - CIF00000000062323</td>
    <td>0001-KAULA LAMPUR</td>
    <td>Hong Leong Bank</td>
    <td>23-06-2020</td>
    <td>Invoice Financing</td>
    <td>23-06-2020</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>CTU2020062310272</td>
    <td>12079404 - CIF00000000062323</td>
    <td>0001-KAULA LAMPUR</td>
    <td>Hong Leong Bank</td>
    <td>23-06-2020</td>
    <td>Letter</td>
    <td>23-06-2020</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @nagasai, you can accept the answer by *clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in*:)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the `tr` element and then find the subjected child element. Once you have it, read the value.

`$(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(7)').text();`